# Route all internet traffic through a single port

Tags: networking, port

I work in a network where internet traffic is blocked and all ports relating to it (80, 443 etc) are closed. But for some reason which I don't know port 53 is open. If I use OpenVPN with certificate that use port 53 with UDP protocol it connects and I have full internet access. Even uTorrent works fine if I change its port to 53. But the VPN service I use is slow.

So my question is there a way to route all internet traffic from this computer through port 53?

I have full admin access on this machine. A solution to this on either Linux or Windows would be enough.

Comment: my question is subverting the corporate firewall going to get you fired?  UDP 53 is only supposed to be used by DNS servers.

Comment: well, that is what the VPN client adapter is doing for you, so expect the same results with any other type of tunnel. Be aware, the way the network is configured, you will be both very easy to catch, and likely to be noticed any which way you go. if they look at top talkers on that port, you will eclipse every other system by orders of magnitude in terms of bandwidth used over UDP/53 (and there will be very few others sense there is no Internet traffic allowed), and openVPN will not hide your host address from the admins internally. additionally they seem well motivated to police the network.

Comment: `I work in a network where internet traffic is blocked` - I suppose it was setup in this way for a reason. I would not try to circumvent it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Comment: @cybernard No it's not going to get me fired. But since the guy below points out there is always going to be overhead i might as well keep using the vpn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do not route all traffic though a single port. It can be done when you create a tunnel (and a VPN is a kind of tunnel), but you will suffer from overhead and at most you will get te slowest performance from either your local connection or from the tunnel end-point.

So no, do not expect things to be spiffy. Especially not if the VPN endpoint is not very fast, and usually those are not set up for speed but for easy of access (e.g. VPN from home to work) or for privacy.

As to why port 53 is open. Port 53 (both for UDP and TCP) is used for DNS. It is often left open because at least some computers will need to access that.

So you can [ab]use that to circumvent the blocks.

Having written that, **I** would consider it abuse to circument the block. If you did that at a place where I was admin I would expect you to come to IT and explain why you need to to have Internet access. Working around it and being found out would mean some harsh words at the very least...

Comment: Well if there is always going to be a performance overhead i might as well not bother. Thanks for the reply. I'm marking this as the answer.